# Substitute the markdown italic to html using regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, markdown, italic

To convert the markdown italic text `$script` into html, I've written this:

```perl
my $script = "*so what*";
my $res =~ s/\*(.)\*/$1/g;
print "<em>$1</em>\n";
```

The expected result is:

```
<em>so what</em>
```

but it gives:

```
<em></em>
```

How to make it give the expected result?

Comment: There are some modules at CPAN already. Just google `perl cpan markdown`. No need to roll yet another.

Comment: I don't think CPAN module should be used for such a simple problem.

Comment: Terry-- This is not so simple at all.  How are you going to handle cases that @ikegami's answer brings up?  And that is not an exhaustive list by any means.

Comment: @zdim Well the target text I 'm processing doesn't contain many of those cases. This doesn't need to be a one-size-fits-for-all solution anyway but rather a quick fix for me who hasn't used regex for years :)

Comment: If you had been using `use warnings` you would have been warned about your problem with the warning `Use of uninitialized value $1 in string... ` It might have alerted you to the fact that your regex didn't match, and in fact you might have figured out that `(.)` needs a quantifier like `+` to match that string. Always use `use strict; use warnings`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems:

- You print the wrong variable.
- You switch variable names halfway through.
- `.` won't match more than one character.
- You always add one EM element, even if no stars are found.
- You always add one EM element, even if multiple pairs of stars are found.
- You add the EM element around the entire output, not just the portion in stars.

Fix:

```perl
$script =~ s{\*([^*]+)\*}{<em>$1</em>}g;
print "$script\n";
```

or

```perl
my $res = $script =~ s{\*([^*]+)\*}{<em>$1</em>}gr;
print "$res\n";
```

But that's not it. Even with all the aforementioned problems fixed, your parser still has numerous other bugs. For example, it misapplies italics for all of the following:

- `**Important**`
  Correct: **Important**
  Your code: **Important**
- `4 * 5 * 6 = 120`
  Correct: 4 * 5 * 6 = 120
  Your code: 4  *5*  6 = 120
- `4 * 6 = 20 is *wrong*`
  Correct: 4 * 6 = 20 is *wrong*
  Your code: 4  *6 = 20 is* wrong*
- `` `foo *bar* baz` ``
  Correct: `foo *bar* baz`
  Your code: `foo *bar* baz`
- `\*I like stars\*`
  Correct: *I like stars*
  Your code: \*I like stars\*

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It worked instantly. I've edited the question, it was missing the `$script`

Comment: 1) That's just one of the *many* things wrong. (See update). 2) Don't (attempt to) edit the question to remove the problem. If you want to post a solution, feel free to answer your own question using an Answer. I have reverted the fix. 3) I had missed that problem. I have updated my answer to address it.